# Access 2016 - Easy multiple user database?

Tags: ms-access-2016

Is there an easy way to set up a database that's accessible to several people that can do all the things a single user would do?

I'm studying Database 101 and I am currently doing a project with four other people and we're having trouble meeting up and doing it so it would be great if we could do it from wherever.

When I say "easy way" I mean without having the super-ultra-deluxe-enterprise-edition of software. 
Can it be done with a "local" Dropbox folder?

Comment: IIRC no. Why does it have to be a access "database". Use something more appropriate for this job, like postgresql or mysql/mariadb. Also, what do you want to do? Select only, insert, update, alter?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do at zero cost is to have one project master.

Distribute a copy to each member. Each will have to do *completely separate tasks*, like one for designing a form, one for adjusting a report, one for some code module, one for another code module.

When done, in the evening or what you agree upon, you collect the different versions with a list of what objects has been changed or added. Import these in your master, and then distribute this to the members as the current revised working copy.

It takes some discipline, but that's all. And all masters you save as a zip given a filename including the date and time. This way, nothing can get lost.